# Want number to limit only up to 2 digit along with upto 7 decimal point- ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have text field called `Decimal value`. If I put a number greater than 99 which is 3digit or more than that, it should give me an error saying *Should be 2 digit decimal/integer non-negative number*, or if I enter a *negative number* it should give same error. It works correctly for negative numbers. But does not work if the number is 100 and greater than 100 i.e. >2digits.

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have written a regular expression for it. But cannot figure out how to deal with 3, 4, or more digits.
Below is the code for it:

`state`

```
this.state = {
  error: {},
  longitude: "",
  number: "",
  alert: false,
};
```

`component`

```
              <Grid>
                <b>Decimal Value</b>
              </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                  <TextField
                    name="number"
                    value={this.state.number}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  {!this.state.number? (
                    <FormHelperText style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      Required
                    </FormHelperText>
                  ) : this.state.alert? (
                    <FormHelperText style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      Should be 2 digit decimal/integer non-negative number
                    </FormHelperText>
                  ) : null}
                </Grid>

                <Button onClick={this.save}>SAVE</Button>
```

`handleChange`

```
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      error: {},
      alert: false,
    });
  };
```

`this.save`

```
  save = async () => {
    let message = false;
    if (!this.state.number||!/^[+]?([1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$/i.test(this.state.number)) {
      this.setState({alert: true});
      message = true;
    }
    if (!this.state.number|| !/^[+-]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$/i.test(this.state.number)) {
      this.setState({alert: true});
      message = true;
    }
  };
```

So, what I want is, the number to be just of 2 digit. It should not exceed more than 2 and upto decimal point of 7. Need help in this as I am trying to do this since one month and cannot figure out what the problem is. Will be very grateful for help.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use regex for this. This should work:

```
  save = async () => {
    let number = parseInt(this.state.number)
    if (number < 0 || number > 99.9999999) {
      this.setState({alert: true});
    } else {
      this.setState({alert: false});
    }
  };
```

**Update**: The regex way to do the same thing

```
  save = async () => {
    let number = this.state.number
    if (!this.state.number||!/^\+?[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,7})?$)$/i.test(this.state.number)) {
      this.setState({alert: true});
    } else {
      this.setState({alert: false});
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought of doing this way. But I kind off wanted it to try with regexp

Comment: In that case this is the right regex - `^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,7})?$`

Comment: I get an error for the statement: 
`Module parse failed: Invalid regular expression: /^\+?[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,7})?$)$/: Unmatched ')' (380:36)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.`

Comment: It does not get saved if the number is between 90 to 100.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. It's working. I spent so much time figuring the regular expression which I wrote....but thank you to you for helping me out.